# Importing parse/node throws an error but works without the import

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

So if you download the Parse platform example nodejs example which can be found here https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example ,
you will notice that Parse does not get imported/required at all.  I know they do not explicitly call Parse in the project, but that is after all the way you do queries, and even initialize the project.

So My problem is, I have a typescript setup but if I import Parse like this 
`import * as Parse from 'parse/node';`

Whenever I do a query it throws me this error.

> ParseError: XMLHttpRequest failed: {"UNSENT":0,"OPENED":1,"HEADERS_RECEIVED":2,"LOADING":3,"DONE":4,"readyState":4,"responseText":"","responseXML":"","status":410,"statusText":null,"withCredentials":false}

I am using these versions in my `package.json`:

```
"parse": "^2.7.1",
"parse-server": "^2.3.3",
```

I have tried to import Parse the old fashioned way with var Parse = require('parse/node'),
Imported the browser version import * as Parse from 'parse'; which just tells me that localstorage has not been set, obviously because its node not Browser.

I tried running the example project by doing a simple query with and without the import and get consistent results, So it does not seem to be a typescript issue.

I tried multiple versions of Parse as well, even version 1.8 which they use in the example project gets the same results.

```js
import express from "express";
import * as PS from 'parse-server';
import path from "path";
import {config} from 'dotenv';
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from 'cors';

import * as Parse from 'parse/node';

config({path:'./env/dev_remote.env'});
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
const ParseServer = PS.ParseServer;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors());

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: process.env.dbUrl + '/' + process.env.dbName,
  appId:'totalProjectServer',
  masterKey:'masterparse',
  serverURL:'http://localhost:1337/parse'
});

app.use('/parse', api);
Parse.initialize('totalProjectServer');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let query = new Parse.Query('NodeExpense');
  query.find().then((data)=>{
    res.status(200).send(data);
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    res.status(500).send(err);
  })
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server running on ${port}`);
})
```

I just want to get my IntelliSense to work and typescript to stop complaining because I am not importing Parse. It just looks wrong if you use functions that are not being imported.

Comment: You don't need to initialize Parse Node.js SDK. Parse Server does it for you. You just need to use it. I'd also recommend you to create cloud code functions instead of creating custom routes in your Express.js application. If you decide to go with your custom router and need to import Parse anyway, try `import Parse from 'parse/node';` but you don't need to initialize again.

Comment: I totally agree and that is what I am seeing. But if I do import 'parse/node'; it either says it needs to be initialized and when i initialize it, it throws out that error mentioned above.

Comment: Have you tried `import Parse from 'parse/node';`?

Comment: I did but same problem.

Comment: I wonder if this has been solved. I'm just back to my project after 4 months - nothing has changed and one of my instances is complaining `You need to call Parse.initialize before using Parse.`

Comment: @ciekawy That was not my issue. Sounds like the Init is not happening when the app starts up.

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to import Parse from a test file and here is the line that worked for me : `import Parse from "parse/node.js";` (notice the presence of the extension `.js`)